# jQuery cycling through nested <li> elements to use :gt

Tags: jquery

Hope you can help. Trying to hide all < li > tags greater than the third tag in an < ul >. What's happening however is that after the first 3 < li > tags, ALL subsequent < li > regardles of :gt(2) are hidden in all subsequent < ul >.

Here's my HTML structure.

- LIST TITLE

  - item 1
  - item 2
  - item 3
  - should be hidden
  - should be hidden
- LIST TITLE

  - item 1
  - item 2
  - item 3
  - should be hidden
  - should be hidden
- LIST TITLE

  - item 1
  - item 2
  - item 3
  - should be hidden
  - should be hidden

And here's my jQuery.

```
$("ul li ul li:gt(2)").each(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

If you need more info let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var counter;
$("ul").each(function() {
    counter = 1;
    $(this).children("li").each(function() {
        if (counter > 3) $(this).hide()
        counter++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, I can't think of a way to work around this with a selector, but you could do it with two selectors:

```
$("ul li ul").each(function () {
    $(this).find("li:gt(2)").hide();
});
```